# Como passar para coluna de um DynamicReports o conteúdo de um objeto composto. sendo que o DataSource é uma lista deste objeto

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Estou fazendo um relatório utilizando DynamicReports

Para isso estou passando uma lista para ser utilizada como DataSource

```
List<VisaoViagemQuadroMensal> linhas = new ArrayList<VisaoViagemQuadroMensal>();
```

onde :

```
public class VisaoViagemQuadroMensal {

    public Linha linha;
    public List<VisaoViagemHorario> horarios;
    // get and set
}

public class Linha {

    private String linha;
    private String descricao;
    private Localidade localidadeDeOrigem;
    private Localidade lovalidadeDeDestino;
    // get and set
}

public class VisaoViagemHorario {
    protected HorarioDaViagem horario;
    protected Sentido sentido;
    protected List<Seccao> seccao;
    protected float km1;
    protected float km2;
    protected float km3;
    protected float kmReal;
    // get and set
}
```

**A duvida é : 
Quando crio o objeto TextColumnBuilder , como faço para informar a descricao da Linha ?
Algo como :**
    linhas.get(0).getLinha().getDescricao();

Abaixo metodo que crio o relatorio

```
protected JasperReportBuilder gerarRelatorio(Collection dataSource, String path, Map parametros) {
JasperReportBuilder report = DynamicReports.report();

// Nesta linha é que esta a duvida
TextColumnBuilder<String> colDescricao  = col.column("Descricao da Linha","???????????", type.stringType() ).setFixedWidth(40);

ImageBuilder imagemLogo = cmp.image( getClass().getResource("/imagens/logoFundoAzul.png") ).setFixedDimension(140, 28);
VerticalListBuilder listParametros = montaParametros(parametros); 

report
  .setPageFormat(PageType.A4, PageOrientation.LANDSCAPE)
  .setPageMargin(margin(20))
  .title(cmp.text("Parametros").setStyle(Estilos.CABECALHO_COLUNA_ESQUERDA.getEstilo()) , listParametros)
  .pageHeader( cmp.horizontalList( imagemLogo, cmp.text("Quadro Demonstrativo por Linhas").setStyle(Estilos.LABEL_TITULO.getEstilo()))).setPageHeaderStyle(Estilos.CABECALHO_PAGINA.getEstilo())
  .pageFooter(cmp.text("www.transportesalvorada.com.br").setStyle(Estilos.LABEL_RODAPE.getEstilo())).setPageFooterStyle(Estilos.CABECALHO_PAGINA.getEstilo())

  .setColumnTitleStyle(Estilos.CABECALHO_COLUNA_ESQUERDA.getEstilo())

  .detail()
     .columns(colDescricao.setStyle(Estilos.LINHA_TOPO.getEstilo())  )
     .highlightDetailEvenRows()

   .setDataSource(new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dataSource));

    //report = report.addProperty(JasperProperty.EXPORT_XLS_FREEZE_ROW, "2");
return report;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quem interessar, depois de muito testar e analisar o fonte,  fiz como o EL do JSF,
retirei o get ao montar o objeto *column*.

Onde em java faço assim:

```
linhas.get(0).getLinha().getLinha();
linhas.get(0).getLinha().getDescricao();
```

No TextColumnBuilder faço assim:

```
linha.linha
linha.descricao
```

Ficando assim:

```
TextColumnBuilder<String> colLinhaCodigo    = col.column("Linha"      ,"linha.linha"    , type.stringType() ).setFixedWidth(30);
TextColumnBuilder<String> colLinhaDescricao = col.column("Descrição"  ,"linha.descricao"    , type.stringType() ).setFixedWidth(100);
```

Comment: Marcelo, se isso resolveu seu problema pode marcar a pergunta como aceita para assim facilitar para outros que tenham a mesma dúvida e entrem no post.